# Dialogs.res, Controls.res not found

Tags: delphi

Both files were not found during the compile process on one dedicated system with Delphi 10.4 and Windows 11.

The complete project has been compiled w/o problems on others systems using Delphi 11 and Delphi 10.3 and Delphi 10.4.

Following the solution from here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3_UVhBbP1s), adding the lib path (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\lib\win64\release`) to the project will not work for us, as we use different Delphi compiler versions inside our team.

Any more general solution for this problem?

Remark :  using different compiler's worked before.  This error appeared just a few days ago, we don't know what is really changed

Comment: Yes, the first step is to give every dev the same version of Delphi for the same project!

Comment: there must be a solution wo all partners using same Delphi version

Comment: Regarding your remark: if your team uses a SCM you could check out an older version and compare against the current project.